# Ansible: Can't set variable for sequential execution

Tags: serialization, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-role

I'm trying to build a playbook with rolling update use case (Sequential Execution) with the `serial` element. Since I have to use the serial value in multiple places in the playbook, I wanted to use it as a variable which can be used to define somewhere as a group variable.

**Inventory file**

```
[all]
webserver1  ansible_host=10.1.1.1 ansible_user=root
webserver2  ansible_host=10.1.1.2 ansible_user=root
webserver3  ansible_host=10.1.1.3 ansible_user=root
dbserver1  ansible_host=10.1.2.1 ansible_user=root

[webserver]
webserver1
webserver2
webserver3

[dbserver]
dbserver1

[app-stack:children]
webservers
dbservers

[app-stack:vars]
app_stack_serial_value=1
```

**Playbook**

```
- hosts: app-stack
  serial: "{{ app_stack_serial_value }}"
  tasks:
   - name: debug
     debug:
       msg: "Ansible Host - {{ ansible_host }}"
```

**Error**

> ERROR! The field 'serial' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'app_stack_serial_value' is undefined

This will work if I specify the value in the serial field like `serial: 1`. But I wanted to use this value as a variable. Any Idea ??

Ansible Version: ansible 2.7.10

python version = 3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:01) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]

Comment: AFAIK this is a reported bug in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33382 All the workarounds out here are pretty ugly.

Comment: You can pass it in as an extra variable: `-e 'app_stack_serial_value=1'`

Comment: @jack I know this will work perfectly, But I wanted to configure it somewhere in the variable file. I have to define multiple serial values based on the group name. I cant put all those variables as an extra variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot set it in the group variables. But you can try set ENV `SERIAL_NUMBER=1` before run this playbook and set the serial parameter like:

```
  serial: "{{lookup('env','SERIAL_NUMBER')|default(3, true)}}"
```